# How can I combine Quorum and Zero Knowledge Range Proofs

Tags: blockchain, zero-knowledge

How can I combine Quorum and Zero Knowledge Range Proofs

I have 20 years of experience at java JEE coding, and 10 years in devops as well,
but no experience with blockchains, or the Go language.

I want to setup a cluster of Quorum blockchain nodes, including the features
provided in ING bank's zkproofs project. I want to be able to complete transactions
where a Prover and Verifier can interact. The Github project provides zero knowledge range proofs
and zero knowledge set membership.

I don't think I'll have much problem bringing up Quorum, but the documentation in the github
project https://github.com/ing-bank/zkproofs is limited! How can I come to understand
how to put the zkrp code with the Quorum nodes, to realize an integrated system? Any tutorials
that would help out there somewhere?